# TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/　error

Tags: python, django

I got an error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/  registration/login.html.

I think I should create login.html file but probably it is not required in Django for default beahivor.

After I placed login.html in accounts/templates/accounts the error has not disappeared.What should I do next?

I wrote in urls.py of accounts,

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login,
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout')
]
```

in urls.py of parent app,

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include('UserToken.urls')),

]
```

in TEMPLATES of settings.py of parent app

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I found in blowser,
emplate-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)

I think maybe I should make templates folder.
Now,I made a directory like accounts/registration/accounts/login.html .
I cannot understand why error shows 2 ways directory to admin&auth.Should I make admin&auth directory?

Comment: Try change settings to 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')] where BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov thx,I added 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts', 'templates', 'accounts')] to settings.py,but I got same error.What should I do?

Comment: what kind of accounts app are you using?

Comment: ＠AlexanderTyapkov accouts app is for login & logout

Comment: I understand that. Is it your own implementation or you have installed with pip? which tutorial did you follow?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov I did pip.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov http://qiita.com/maueki/items/d28fd2a170d42e745376  I followed this (it is written in Japanese).I wote all codes in the web.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov anyway,I wanna complete login & logout system.So,any method to make is ok for me.

Comment: please provide the structure of the project and your accounts/urls.py

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov Now my app is like App(parent app)/App(parent app)/accounts. In accounts,it is like accounts/migration&templates folders and models.py & urls.py & views.py & app.py etc.

Comment: You *do* need to create a login template, Django does not come with one. As the error message suggests, Django is looking for the template in  `accounts/templates/registration/login.html`, not `accounts/templates/accounts/login.html`. If `accounts` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`, then you shouldn't need to change `DIRS`, since you have already set `'APP_DIRS` to `True`.

Comment: @Alasdair thx,I found accounts in INSTALLED_APPS.Now,I made 
 'DIRS': [],       in TEMPLATES of settings.py of parent app.But i got same error.WHat should i do?

Comment: The template should be `accounts/templates/registration/login.html`. If you're still stuck you need to update your question with the exact layout of your project and your current error message. At the moment it's not clear what you are trying.

Answer (score 4):

For me worked adding:

```
 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Take care to delete browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

The pathnames in your error messages are showing a space character just after **login/** - this is probably not contained in the actual filenames, thus the files can't be found.  In one case it's a normal space, in the other it's a Unicode 'IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE' (U+3000). I don't see where this is coming from in your source code.

Comment: thx,I wanna check Unicode 'IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE' (U+3000) of ur comments ,but I do not know how.What should i do?

Comment: I have no idea how you'd type one of those intentionally.  You could copy & paste one from the title of your question at the top of this page - the space between __login/__ and __error__ is one of them.  If your code editor has a "show invisibles" or similar feature, it might reveal any that had been accidentally typed in your code.

Answer (score 0):

check all your folders name what you put same Error I also receiving.
I mistakenly put template instead of templates.
Django default takes templates folder rather than just template or any other name.
This resolves my problem.